# Why Are All the Early Star Trek Doctors Racists? Did Gene Roddenberry Hate Medical Doctors?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos

Bones hardly goes an episode without pointing out how Spock is not human, and that makes him inherently inferior. They are clearly friends, but Bones is casually racist. The striking part is that I do not think a single other member of the crew ever does anything similar with regard to any species.

This alone is a strange and striking aspect of TOS, but in TNG it becomes a pattern. In TNG Spock is replaced by Data, and again the medical doctor of the enterprise is the only character who does not believe that a mechanical being can be alive, conscious, or matter. Every series after Gene Roddenberry's death features doctors with, arguably, bigger roles and who continually show themselves to be the most empathetic and open minded of their crews.

Comment: But it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Sometimes question are closed as duplicates not because the question text itself is duplicated, but because the question will solicit the same answer. In this case I believe the answer to this question is "The doctors were racist because that was supposed to be a reflection of the time period (meaning the time that show was produced)", which is the same answer on linked question.

Comment: @Skooba - Indeed. That being said, the question about Pulaski being "racist" (speciesist?) toward Data is somewhat new. If you cropped everything about Bones/Spock out of the question, it wouldn't be a dupe any more.

Comment: @Skooba How so? That would only be the setup before explaining why Gene, or someone else, decided that the doctor of the ship in each series was the best foil for this racist dialogue. I am not asking why Gene, et al, decided to include racism in ST, but why it was almost exclusively racism coming from the main Doctor of the ship (in each series). I would not consider any answer that was at all like the one(s) in the linked question as appropriate or worthy of my vote.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski Check out Valorum's comment, there may be a simple edit to get your question reopened. I was merely trying to provide some context as to why those who closed your question did so, as I know it can frustrating at time when feel it was incorrectly.

Comment: I don't even pick up from McCoy the idea that Spock is inferior.  If anything, the subtext from TOS about Vulcans was always that they are our overall superiors in virtually every way.  He does critique Spock for being *psychologically different*, chiefly around emotion - and Spock would certainly have completely agreed with that expression of difference.  Frankly Spock probably discusses his lack of humanity more than Bones - sometimes lamenting it, but sometimes BRAGGING about it (in a completely logical way, of course).

Comment: TBH, the doctor in the TOS pilot did not seem to be racist.